# jRuby or Groovy for a new project? What is the best option?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, grails, groovy, jruby

I'm starting a new project and i want to make it using some language that runs on top of JVM and i'm thinking to use jRuby/RoR or Groovy/Grails.

What is the best option?

Thank you.

Comment: Please give enough specifications of the project that the choice of language or framework would make a difference - then someone answering the question could refer to why it was a better choice for you. Otherwise, you can just pick your favourite language and framework.

Comment: To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?” — cited from [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 3):

"Best Option" is very subjective. Everyone has his their own preferences and set of acceptable tradeoffs. That said I'll write about my opinion and please don't start language wars here.

So, it depends a lot on what you and your team is already familiar with. If you have done Rails stuff a lot, JRuby/Rails make sense. Keep in mind, you still need to understand a fair amount of JVM ecosystem in order to have rails app running on JVM. Some of gems that utilize native code wont work here.

Groovy/grails stands on solid foundation of stable java framework and productive a language called Groovy. It's very easy to pick up if you have done even some Java earlier.

Groovy is a native JVM language (that means, it was made to run with JVM/Java interoperability in mind) while JRuby is a Ruby port on JVM. That brings Groovy in a better position for me on JVM. Again Your mileage may vary.

Both Grails and Rails are tested and stable frameworks. Rails has better ecosystem than Grails. But Grails is better choice if you have to stick with JVM.